# How to display content of file with using system() in c++?

Tags: c++, text, system

I got until here .argv[1] is file name which is from command line...

```
std::string first ("cat"); 
std::string second (argv[1]); 
std::string command=firstlevel+secondlevel; 
system(command);
```

Comment: so, you are struggling with getting the contents of the file? or displaying the contents?

Comment: i am trying to display contents of the file. Sorry forgot to mention. Yes i am using fork(). in the parent I need to use system() to display whatever is in the file.

Answer (score 2):

You have it almost right, note though you have no space between cat and argv[1] and system takes a `const char*` as argument, not a `std::string`

```
std::string firstlevel ("cat"); 
std::string secondlevel (argv[1]); 
std::string command=firstlevel+" "+secondlevel;  // add space between
system(command.c_str());  // pass const char*
```

However, beware of [code injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

Comment: Good, but beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)., which should be mentioned in the answer.What if `argv[1]` is the string `"foo; rm -rf $HOME"` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch true enough

Comment: To avoid code injection before calling `system()` just check presence of file with name `argv[1]`

Comment: That still won't work, imagine if the OP *had* a file with a strange name like `"foo; rm -rf $HOME"` (and even any file name with a `$` would not work)

Comment: It is same as what I have explained conceptually, I could not type more from a mobile

Answer (score 1):

`man 3 system` gives following synopsis

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 int system(const char *command);
```

So, we need to give the `argument` to system as `char or const char`

So you will need to get the `char` from `std::string` using `c_str()` on

```
command.c_str()
```

So, Your final code will look something like, as suggested by @Anders K

```
std::string firstlevel ("cat");
std::string secondlevel (argv[1]);
std::string command=firstlevel + " " + secondlevel;
system( command.c_str() );
```